# Global "App" controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have noticed in a few tutorials and code examples floating around the internet developers using a global AppController in their applications and modules.

**Is it best practice to create a global AppController in AngularJS?**

I do see some benefits such as being able to handle events in a "global" scope such as:

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $rootScope, $route, $location){

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, current, previous) {
        console.log('Do something...');
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
        console.log('Do something...);
    });
});
```

are there any other **advantages** or **disadvantages** to this pattern?

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal There are situations where broadcast serves its purpose in an app level controller. You can't just dismiss them in a single context and brand any applications "non-module" that uses them.

Answer (score 4):

Purely in context of situation. Let's take an example of dynamically changing title tags and page view:

```
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: '/views/home.html',
    title:'Home'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

.controller('app', ['$scope','$route','$location',function($scope,$route,$location){
  $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function($currentRoute,$previousRoute ){
    $scope.title = $route.current.title;
    $scope.page = $route.current.template;
  });
}]);
```

Now both our title and page view are being dynamically loaded in through app level controller that wraps our application. This can be very useful.

```
<html lang="en" ng-controller="app">
<head>
<title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<ng-include src="page"></ng-include>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example of when not to use it. Let's say one of our partial pages return data from an API:

```
<!-- search.html -->
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{item.title}}
</div>
```

And in our app level controller we are pulling data via broadcast:

```
$scope.$on('searchComplete',function(d){
  $scope.items = d
});
```

That partial will show the data as we intended however - problems could arise when other child partials use `items` where scope is being overwritten.

```
<!-- other-search.html -->
<div ng-controller="OtherSearch" ng-click="search()">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{item.title}}
</div>
</div>
```

In this partial, `ng-click` is guiding the users request. So if the app level controller already binded `items` in the parent, the user will see a list of items when toggling to this partial even if they never triggered the action of `search()`.

Comment: Nice.  This came in handy for me.